# How to do webscraping faster with Selenium and multiprocessing?

Tags: python, selenium

With the code bellow, I am able to do webscraping of list of websites. I wonder how can i use multiprocessing to make this wescraping faster.

Basicaly what I want is to make the `for j in list_j` iterate over the `list_j` all elements at once instead of one by one.

Is this possible?

```
from selenium import webdriver

list_j = ['17098794000170', '17144039000185', '10347985000180', '32784898000122']

def do_stuf():
    print('Here I do some webscraping')

for j in list_j:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/abrirGerenciadorDocumentosCVM?cnpjFundo=' + j)
    do_stuf()
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want fast scraping https://scrapy.org is a lot faster(it just scrapes things and then process it), sometime you can even use requests, only use selenium for JavaScript heavy things as its slow.

Also a simple request based spider, to serve as an example (this one that requires auth:

```
import datetime
import logging
import os
import glob

import dropbox
import pandas as pd
import requests

import paramaters

logger = logging.getLogger("tt_api")
logging.basicConfig(
    filename="tt_api_" + datetime.date.today().strftime("%V") + ".log",
    level=logging.INFO,
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s",
)  # nieuwe log elke week

login_token = requests.post(
    "https://api.tt.nl/api/account/login",
    json={
        "email": paramaters.tt_gebruiker,
        "password": paramaters.tt_wachtwoord,
    },
)
if login_token.status_code != 200:
    logger.error(f"error login{login_token.status_code}")

token = "Bearer " + login_token.json()["token"]

aantal_producten = 96

producten = []

doorgaan = True


def get_products(page, aantal_producten=24):
    global doorgaan
    payload = (
        '{"page":'
        + str(page)
        + ',"query":null,"pageSize":'
        + str(aantal_producten)
        + ',"sorts":[{"field":"popularity","desc":true}],"filters":[{"ref":"voorraad","options":[{"r":"ja"}]}],"filtersChanged":true,"countsOnly":true}'
    )
    headers = {"Authorization": token, "Content-Type": "application/json"}

    response = requests.request(
        "POST",
        "https://api.tt.nl/api/shop/tags/1001/read-v2",
        headers=headers,
        data=payload,
    )
    producten.extend(response.json()["rows"])
    if len(response.json()["rows"]) != aantal_producten:
        doorgaan = False


for page in range(1, 15):
    if not doorgaan:
        break
    get_products(page, aantal_producten)

beschikbare_artikelen = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(producten)

beschikbare_artikelen["brand"] = pd.DataFrame.from_records(beschikbare_artikelen.brand)
image = pd.DataFrame.from_records(beschikbare_artikelen.image).add_prefix('image_')

category = pd.DataFrame.from_records(beschikbare_artikelen.category).add_prefix('category_')
# highlights = pd.DataFrame.from_records(beschikbare_artikelen.highlights).add_prefix('highlights_')

beschikbare_artikelen_concat = pd.concat([beschikbare_artikelen,image, category],axis = 1).drop(columns={"image","category","highlights"})

beschikbare_artikelen_concat['image_fileName'] = 'https://api.tt.nl/images/' + beschikbare_artikelen_concat['image_fileName'].astype(str)

beschikbare_artikelen_concat.to_csv("T_artikelen_" + paramaters.date_now + ".csv", index=False)

final_tt = max(glob.iglob("T_artikelen_*.csv"), key=os.path.getctime)

dbx = dropbox.Dropbox("")
with open(final_tt, "rb") as f:
            dbx.files_upload(f.read(), '/macro/datafiles/T/'+ final_tt , mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode('overwrite', None), mute = True)
```

Comment: I have a difficulty scrapping iframes out of selenium

Comment: If i see the page, you can just donload the xml files with scrapy, and then process them. i don't see the need for iframes ? as the xml contains al the data from the preview ?

Comment: I am not looking for xml files, just need to save the table to an sql base with the visualization and download url. I need to monitor 24/7 more then 340 different J's on list_j, and don't want to wait for an iteration of all of them to update my history database for each J

Comment: What exactly do you need ? as with requests jou could quickly fetch the content of the main pages and then extract the info from the json. requests.get(http://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/pesquisarGerenciadorDocumentosDados?d=1&s=0&l=10&o%5B0%5D%5BdataEntrega%5D=desc&tipoFundo=1&administrador=299&cnpjFundo=32784898000122&idCategoriaDocumento=0&idTipoDocumento=0&idEspecieDocumento=0&_=1607169722546) also don't fetch all at the same time it just will get you blocked !

Comment: How can i extract the webpage as you did on that link? http://fnet.bmfbovespa.com.br/fnet/publico/pesquisarGerenciadorDocumentosDados?d=1&s=0&l=10&o%5B0%5D%5BdataEntrega%5D=desc&tipoFundo=1&administrador=299&cnpjFundo=32784898000122&idCategoriaDocumento=0&idTipoDocumento=0&idEspecieDocumento=0&_=1607169722546

Comment: You can get it by looking at the requests your browser is making look onder Browser Console network,  you also have to add the right headers or cookies, or auth a lot off times.